# Select single row based on Id in Slick

Tags: scala, slick, scalaquery

I want to query a single row from user based on Id. I have following dummy code

```
case class User(
    id: Option[Int], 
    name: String
}

object Users extends Table[User]("user") {
  def id = column[Int]("id", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
  def name = column[String]("name")
  def * = id ~ name <>(User, User.unapply _)

  def findById(userId: Int)(implicit session: Session): Option[User] = {
    val user = this.map { e => e }.where(u => u.id === userId).take(1)
    val usrList = user.list
    if (usrList.isEmpty) None
    else Some(usrList(0))
  }
}
```

It seems to me that `findById` is a overkill to query a single column as Id is standard primary key. Does anyone knows any better ways? Please note that I am using Play! 2.1.0

Comment: A very nice example: https://www.becompany.ch/en/blog/2016/12/15/slick-dos-and-donts

Answer (score 19):

Use `headOption` method in Slick 3.*:

```
  def findById(userId: Int): Future[Option[User]] ={
    db.run(Users.filter(_.id === userId).result.headOption)
  }
```

Comment: Is there a way to do something similar as in LINQ where there is a .First() method and also a .Single() method?
.First simply returns the first "row" and .Single throws an exception if there is more than 1 row in the result set.

Answer (score 6):

You could drop two lines out of your function by switching from `list` to `firstOption`.  That would look like this:

```
def findById(userId: Int)(implicit session: Session): Option[User] = {
  val user = this.map { e => e }.where(u => u.id === userId).take(1)
  user.firstOption
}
```

I believe you also would do your query like this:

```
def findById(userId: Int)(implicit session: Session): Option[User] = {
  val query = for{
    u <- Users if u.id === userId
  } yield u
  query.firstOption
}
```

Comment: Do you think firstOption may have been removed from lifted.Query in Slick 2.1?  I believe it has been.  http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/2.1.0/api/#scala.slick.lifted.Query

Comment: It's gone - this answer is outdated now

Answer (score 3):

`firstOption` is a way to go, yes.

Having

```
  val users: TableQuery[Users] = TableQuery[Users]
```

we can write

```
def get(id: Int): Option[User] = users.filter { _.id === id }.firstOption
```

Answer (score 0):

A shorter answer.

```
  `def findById(userId: Int)(implicit session: Session): Option[User] = {
     User.filter(_.id === userId).firstOption
        }`
```

Answer (score 0):

```
case class User(
    id: Option[Int], 
    name: String
}

object Users extends Table[User]("user") {
  def id = column[Int]("id", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
  def name = column[String]("name")
  def * = id.? ~ name <>(User.apply _, User.unapply _)
  // .? in the above line for Option[]

  val byId = createFinderBy(_.id)
  def findById(id: Int)(implicit session: Session): Option[User] = user.byId(id).firstOption
```